# 'int' object is not iterable, however those are Arrays of int.. not just int

Tags: python

Hi i'm having an error with this piece of code, i can't see where it comes from. Any idea ?

```
def collision2(tab1,tab2):

    for i in range(len(tab1)):
        for j in range(len(tab2)):
            if (tab1[i]==tab2[j]):
                return i,j
    return -1
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, I suspect, in how you return and interpret the results of the function. If there is a match, the function returns a tuple, but if not `-1`. You probably *unpack the results of the function* and, if there is no match, you get this error:

```
>>> def collision2(tab1,tab2):
...     for i in range(len(tab1)):
...         for j in range(len(tab2)):
...             if (tab1[i]==tab2[j]):
...                 return i,j
...     return -1
... 
>>> x, y = collision2([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])  # there is a match, no error
>>> x, y = collision2([1, 2, 3], [10, 10, 10])  # now, there is no match
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

---

One way to fix it would be to return `-1, -1` tuple instead of just `-1`:

```
def collision2(tab1,tab2):
    for i in range(len(tab1)):
        for j in range(len(tab2)):
            if (tab1[i] == tab2[j]):
                return i,j
    return -1, -1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are currently seeing is a tuple unpack error, if there are no common elements in **tab1** and **tab2** you only return **-1** as a result when you all the function as:

```
x, y = collision2([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

**y** doesn't get assigned a value, causing an exception to be raised

Hence you can implement the function like this:

```
def collision2(tab1, tab2):
    for idx1, val1 in enumerate(tab1):
        for idx2, val2 in enumerate(tab2):
            if val1 == val2:
                return idx1, idx2
    return -1, -1
```

Two things to note:

1. Returning -1, -1 prevents tuple unpack error
2. using `enumerate(iterable)` returns both the index and value at that index of the iterable. This practice is considered pythonic.

Hope this helps.